# Is there documentation for Ubuntu Studio operating system?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I would like to learn about Ubuntu Studio, is there any documentation for it?
If possible I would like the documentation in PDF format.

Answer (score 5):

you can see the Official UbuntuStudio guide here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UserGuide

[image]

Comment: Also upper level at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio and https://ubuntustudio.org/support/ .